# Combinatoric Optimization - Enumerating all Subsets that Contain a Given Set

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of sets S = { s1, s2, s3 .. } and a set of elements X = { x1, x2, x3 .. } how can I enumerate all sets Y where the elements of set Y are drawn from S with replacement, and X is a subset of the union of set Y. Right, here's what I have so far (python):

```
def enumerate_containing_subsets(S, X):
    if not set(X).issubset(set().union(*S)): return
    previous_generation = [[]]
    for element in X:
        current_generation = []
        for subset in S:
            if element in subset:
                for node in previous_generation:
                    current_generation.append( node + [subset] )
        previous_generation = current_generation
    return previous_generation

S = [ frozenset([1,2]), frozenset([3]), frozenset([4,1])]
X = [ 1, 2 ]
enumerate_containing_subsets(S, X)
>> [[frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([1, 2])], 
    [frozenset([1, 4]), frozenset([1, 2])]]
```

This naive approach is *O*(n^n) I think, I'm essentially building a tree here and branching at each generation for each possible element of S that contains the next value of X, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: So you essentially want some subset of P(S) such that the union contains X.

Comment: Yes, I want to optimize my cost function over all such subsets

Comment: What's your cost function?

Comment: The cost function is not so important here, I just want to make sure I enumerate every possible subsets that meets my criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
# Ruby
require 'set'
s = Set[Set[1, 2, 3, 4], Set[3, 4, 5], Set[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]]
x = Set[1, 3, 4]

class Set
    def powerset 
        inject(Set[Set[]]) do |ps, item| 
            ps.union ps.map {|e| e.union (Set.new [item])}
        end
    end
end
pow = s.powerset
pow.select! { |sub|x <= sub.flatten }
p pow
```

This is `O(n * x * 2^n)` since we must iterate over the powerset `2^n` and execute `n` unions (constant time) + x queries to see if X is in the sets.